# Updating a chart from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Currently I have a set of values from a sensor being captured from a thread. I want to plot these values onto a chart in "real-time", say every 1 second.

So what I normally do is this (in a non-threaded version):

1) Get data into a List

2) Click a button to run `myChart.Refresh()`

3) Trigger the `OnPaint()` to draw the graph.

However, I realised that I cannot trigger `OnPaint()` within a thread. I also know that there is a `BackgroundWorker` class but I am not sure how to trigger the `OnPaint()` method with that as well.

Comment: Do you have already a code for threading?

Comment: Try to write the code 'Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls=false' within form load event and hence you can call _OnPaint()_ method from your thread without using _BackgroundWorker_

Answer (score 0):

The OnPaint() can be called only on the Main UI thread, as it needs to draw the graph and update the UI. You can interact and perform UI actions from any thread using Dispatcher Class.
Refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand more about dispatchers.